# Pagination for query_posts();

Tags: categories, query-posts, pagination

I know there have been many question like this and I've read them, but I still cant get it working... I have this query:

```
query_posts(array('cat'=>3,'posts_per_page'=>5));
```

And I simply display the content below in  `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` loop
How can I add pagination to this?
I'm trying with adding `posts_nav_link();` ( I don't know is it the right function to call what I want) and links displayed take me to http://mysite.com/page/2. Since its my index page its ok to not add category name in link (its news page) but after clicking on the link, when I'm on the page/2/ news simply doesn't change. I still see the first page of my news without change... I think I need to add attribute of 'paged' to my query, but how and where? I've tried `'paged'=>'paged'` in array but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

try adding :

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

and then in your args array add `'paged'=> $page`

Comment: Yeah, that works but now I have another problem. While its my index page "next" link takes me to mywebsite.com/page/2 and it doesnt work cause it should be mysite.com/news/page/2 How can I add "news/" to adress?

Comment: why? whats your permalink structure, also did you recently change it?

Comment: Thats my structure (didn't configured clear links yet): /index.php/%category%/%postname%/ and yeah, I did changed it recently.

Comment: i wonder how many times this question is asked. We should have a commonly asked question page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in WP that causes pagination errors if you have duplicate slugs/names between a custom post type and a Page. If you have a custom post type called `news` and a page that  also has a slug of `news`, your pagination will not work with `query_posts`.

To fix this, change the slug of your News page to something else and reset your permalinks. Should be all set.

(sorry this is a separate answer- I just joined and dont see the option to 'reply' to a previous Answer)